# Receiving Error Message, despite data being sent

Tags: php

I have recently implemented a number of `if` statements that check to see if the require data has been entered, if not then I receive the error message `something is wrong with...`. But after implementing them I now recieve that error message regardless of whether the data is in fact being sent to the database (the data that is being sent is all correct) and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
$query = "insert into $sql_table (Eoi, Job_reference_number, First_Name, Last_Name, Street_Address, Suburb, State, Postcode, Email, Phone_Number, Skills) values ('$eoi','$jobNumber', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$streetAddress', '$suburb', '$state', '$postcode', '$emailAddress', '$phoneNumber', '$skills')";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if($jobNumber = ''){
       $result = false;
    }
    if($firstName = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your First Name </p>";    
    }

    if($lastName = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Last Name </p>";
    }

    if($streetAddress = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Street Address </p>";
    }
    if($suburb = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Suburb </p>";            
    }
    if($postcode = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Postcode </p>";
    }
    if($email = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Email </p>";     
    }
    if($phoneNumber = ''){
    $result = false;
        echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Phone Number </p>";
    }
    if($skills = ''){
    $result = false;
    echo "<p> Something is wrong with your Skills </p>";        
    }


if($result != mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "<p>Something is wrong with ", $query, "</p>";
}else {
    echo "<p class=\"ok\">Successfully added a New EOI record</p>";
    }   
    }
}
        mysqli_close($conn);
```

I expect the result to be `Successfully added a new EOI record` when the user inputs valid data but instead I get the error message.

Comment: after `inserting` your values in db, why are you checking for `empty` values , that should be check before `insert` query ,also `=` should be `==`.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that you are already inserting the data before checking for errors. Plus, you are not stopping if you receive an error

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

> First you have a syntax error in if statement
>   if statement should be `==` not `=`

```
if($yourVariable == ''){
  echo "<p> Something is wrong with your yourVariable </p>";//no meaning of this line
  $result = false;
}
```

it means if your `variable` is `empty` then `$result` will `false` and you're can check it in your last if

> Second you are checking all variable after DB insertion, you need to do it before insertion in db